# How to create a vertex at an intersection of two edges with TinyCad?

Tags: snapping

I'm trying to place a vertex at the intersection of two edges using TinyCAD in Blender 3.1.0, but nothing happens when I:
1 - select the edges in edge mode
2 - right-click tinyCAD>V2X

Is the vertex supposed to be generated immediately at that point?

The planes are on the same, um, plane.

[image]

Comment: Are both of these planes part of the same object or are they separate objects entirely?

Comment: Separate objects

Comment: Okay, so I tried it when they are part of the same object.  Looks like that makes a new vertex.  Thank you!

Comment: *crowd cheering*